# Linux "du" command, only for a specific file extension

Tags: linux, disk-usage

I have a folder with a lot of subfolders.
I need to scan for all the `.pst` file inside the folder and subfolder, then I need to know the disk space size total of all the `.pst` files found.

Example:

```
\myfolder\file1.pst 10gb
\myfolder\mysubfolder\file2.pst 2gb
\myfolder\mysubdolder\mysubsubfolder\file3.pst 8gb

Total size of all .pst files: 20gb.
```

How can I do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming GNU tools (which is reasonable to assume on a Linux system):

```bsh
find myfolder -type f -name '*.pst' -print0 |
du --human-readable --total --files0-from=-
```

This finds all regular files with names matching the pattern `*.pst` in or under the `myfolder` directory.  The pathname of each such file is passed in a nul-delimited list to `du`, which reads them from standard input and reports the total size taken by the files.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a list of file names as input to `du` (assuming the GNU version, which is the one on non-embedded Linux).

```
find myfolder -name '*.pst' -print0 | du --files0-from=- -c
```

Alternatively, if the list of file names isn't too long, you can make the shell pass it on the command line. This works out of the box with zsh, and requires `shopt -s globstar` on bash.

```
cd myfolder
du -c -- **/*.pst
```